# Plotly.js show error 'Uint8ClampedArray' is undefined when used in Internet explorer 11

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-11, plotly

I have created a graph in the plotly. When i have tried that in internet explorer, its stuck. It show enything on the graph. When i tried the development option it shows 'Uint8ClampedArray' is undefined. What is the problem? How can i overcome this problem. Will you please help me to solve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>Untitled</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tester" style="width:600px;height:250px;"></div>
<script>
TESTER = document.getElementById('tester');
Plotly.plot( TESTER, [{
x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
y: [1, 2, 4, 8, 16] }], {
margin: { t: 0 } } );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The errors shown are given below.
SCRIPT5009: 'Uint8ClampedArray' is undefined
SCRIPT5009: 'Plotly' is undefined

Comment: It's impossible to help unless you show us your code and the error it produces

Comment: I have provided the code. This code works normally in firefox and chrome. Why shouldn't in the IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. The problem was with Internet Explorer and i have updated to a latest version. Hence it support Uint8ClampedArray and now its work.

Thank you everyone who consider my question

Comment: But is there a way out if someone has to stick with the same IE version?

Comment: @YashPShah. yes you are write but there is not  other way.